# Execute multiple queries at same time, if the all the queries are valid then only I should get the response in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to execute 2 queries at the same time, for example, refer below:

`db.getCollection('Test').find({'color':'red'},{'color':'yellow'});`

Assume that color red is present in the one collection and yellow is present in another collection, but I am getting the response only from the first query.

Expectation:
1.If both the queries are present in any of the collection I should get both 
  responses.
2.If anyone of the query is invalid or element is not present in the collection, 
  I should not get any response.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean document in a collection?

Comment: post data sample for better response.

Comment: @Siva Narayanan
Mind to post data set?

Comment: Posted an answer, check it out and if more changes required, please respond with data set. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to match existence of both values, use `$all` operator:

```
db.getCollection('Test').find({color:{$all:["red","yellow"]}})
```

### Edit

I managed to get your output, but I think this could be simplified. I thought about different options and ended up in this query:

```
db.colors.aggregate([{
  $facet:{
      cond1:[{$match:{color:"red"}}],
      cond2:[{$match:{color:"yellow"}}]
  }},

  {$project:{match1: "$cond1", match2:"$cond2" ,size1:{$size: "$cond1"}, 
  size2:{$size: "$cond2"}}},

  {$project:{result:{$cond:[{$and:[{$gte:["$size1",1]},{$gte:
  ["$size2",1]}]},{$concatArrays:["$match1","$match2"]},[]]}}}

])
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Rahul, I have tried this query but the problem is if we use all, the search elements red and yellow should present in the same document then only I will give the response. But my scenario is red is from one document and yellow is from another document.

Comment: Why can't you post the data set?

Comment: For example, I have 2 documents,
document 1:
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ab9433d7f507345e4b64559"),
    "color" : "red"
}

document 2:
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ab9434d7f507345e4b6455a"),
    "color" : "yellow"
}

My Scenario, I should get response If I search with the color yellow and red but If I search with yellow and white **(white is not present in any documents )** then I should not get any response.That is my expectation

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong with your question.
I think you are looking for something like this `db.getCollection('Test').find({color: {$in: ['red','yellow']}});`
I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response!!!
Actually, there are two cases one is OR search and another one is AND search._The above query is working fine for OR search it will give the response if anyone of the element is valid(red or yellow)_
**I am looking solution for AND search all the search elements should be present in the documents then only it should give the response**.
please let me know if you need additional info.
thanks in advance

Comment: For example, I have 2 documents,
document 1:
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ab9433d7f507345e4b64559"),
    "color" : "red"
}

document 2:
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ab9434d7f507345e4b6455a"),
    "color" : "yellow"
}

My Scenario, I should get response If I search with the color yellow and red but If I search with yellow and white **(white is not present in any documents )** then I should not get any response.That is my expectation